# Is it possible to define a number, order preserving map, or functional $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\mathbb{N}$ has Lebesgue measure $1$?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, measure-theory

Is it possible to define a number, order preserving map, or functional  $\alpha$ such that $\alpha\mathbb{N}=\{x|x=\alpha n $ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and the Lebesgue outter measure $m^*(\alpha\mathbb{N})=1$?

What if there is a further restriction such that $\alpha\mathbb{N}\in[0,1)$?

(I was thinking about some number like $\frac{1}{\omega}$)

Comment: Numbers, order preserving maps, and functionals are very different things and give αN different meanings. Can you clarify what you’re looking for more?

Comment: I guess the $\frac{1}{\omega}$ idea fails due to countability. Countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are lebesgue null sets.

Comment: In general though, the Lebesgue outer measure agrees with the Lebesgue measure when the later is defined. $\mathbb N$ is countable and so unless your transformation is one-to-many you can’t do this.

Comment: @StellaBiderman I was thinking may be we can define such number, but then I'm not sure weather being a number can conclude the existence, because $\frac{1}{\omega}$ ic certainly not in $R$ or $C$. But in this case, the multiplicaiton was essentially empherize order preserving, so such "number"(if it exists) act on $\mathbb{N}$ can be equivelent defined as a map or linear functional. Further, it's expected that if such map exists, (and, for example, confined $\mathbb{N}$ to $[0,1)$), it would also make $\alpha\mathbb{N}$ a "dense" set in a non traditional way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb N$ is countable, and any countable set has Lebesgue (outer) measure $0$. Therefore in order for this to work, you would have to pick a one-to-many mapping, and specifically one that maps a single point to uncountably many points. I’m not 100% sure what you’re after, but I doubt that that’s what you’re after. So, I’m going to say the answer is **no you cannot**.

Comment: Think about $t_n=\frac{1}{n}$
where $t_n\cdot n=1$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n\cdot \mathbb{N}$. It's converge to $0$, but if we restrict $t=\lim_{n\in \mathbb{N}}sup(t_n)$, then it seemes intuition to me that $t$ should be the cardinal number $\frac{1}{\mathbb{N}_0}>0$. and $t\mathbb{N}$.

It's not a one to one map as you pointed out, in a sense that $\frac{1}{\mathbb{N}_0}$ acturally created an equivelance class of infinitismal, so $\frac{1}{\mathbb{N}_0}$ mapped each element in $\mathbb{N}$ to a set of equivelance class,

Comment: in a sence that $m^*(\frac{1}{\mathbb{N}_0} \cdot \mathbb{N} )=m^*(\frac{1}{\mathbb{N}_0}\cdot \mathbb{R})$ Could that work?

Comment: @JC There is no cardinal $1/\mathbb N$. Using any properties of cardinals will immediately break whatever you’re trying to do.

Comment: @JC I am not sure that $\frac 1 t \mathbb N$ is supposed to mean either.

Comment: @JC very little in measure theory comes out okay if you’re mapping $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ to the same place though. That’s a huge red flag. You should edit the question to explain what you mean / what you are trying to say (and include all non-standard definitions you wish to use), but the answer to the current question is definitely no.